# g++ refuses to compile

Tags: c++

Is the software defective? I've rechecked many times and can't see a problem. All the brackets line up, the code is correct, nothing is missing? Why the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int letters; //Total number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                              
  int digits; //Total number of digits                                                                                                                                             
  int sentencecount; //Number of sentences                                                                                                                                         
  float averageletters; //Average number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                   
  int linecount=0; //Count of lines                                                                                                                                                
  char current; //Current character                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  cin.get(current);
  while (cin)
    {
      digits = 0;
      letters = 0;
      linecount++;
      while (current != '\n')
        {
          if (current == ' ')
              digits++;
          //calcuate averages and other sentence data                                                                                                                              
          //reset sentence data                                                                                                                                                    
          if (isalpha(current))//repeat for digits                                                                                                                                 
            letters++;
          cin.get (current);
        }
      cout << "ine # " << linecount << digits << letters << endl;
      cin.get (current);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

It's 67,000 characters long and the limit on Stackexchange is 3000. This is the best I can do : pastebin.com/wQ2qRjhA

Comment: `cin.get{current);`  See something wrong?

Comment: You know, the errors your compiler give you are supposed to help you.

Comment: The first [error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec5c4eeb4df35da5) points directly at the problem.

Comment: I fixed it but it still doesnt compie

Comment: You need to specify your errors.  Just edit the compiler errors into your post

Comment: Compiles and runs on ideone (after fixing `{`): https://ideone.com/wiAii0

Comment: It's 67,000 characters long and the limit on Stackexchange is 3000. This is the best I can do : pastebin.com/wQ2qRjhA

Comment: The very first line of that error message points you to line 2 of testdata.cpp.

Comment: The error is telling you the exact problem. You have an errant letter "y" on that line. Don't be intimidated by all those errors. Often one small error can cascade into many. Focus on one at a time.

Comment: Usually, the first message is labeled "error" and tells you what is wrong. That might be followed by messages that are labeled "note", and they give you more details about the problem. Then there can be another "error", and maybe more "note"s, and so on. Start with the first error. That might have caused an error cascade -- the rest of the error messages might be caused by the first one. So keep it simple, and only look at the first error; fix it, compile again, and repeat until done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrote in line 14

```
 cin.get{current);
```

You simply have a typo error. Just change `{` to `(`

```
cin.get( current);
```

Comment: I fixed it but it still doesn't work. It puked up a novel-sized error message instead. Something about streamsize.

Comment: Could you please post your exact error?

Comment: It's 67,000 characters long and the limit on Stackexchange is 3000. This is the best I can do : https://pastebin.com/wQ2qRjhA

Comment: Well that are erros, which have nothing to do with your posted code? There is no variable `y`

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. Y ended up in the comment section.